# Alternative HTTP clients to RestTemplate for non spring boot projects

Tags: java, web, client, httpclient, resttemplate

I am developing a Java application (not Spring Boot).

What are alternative HTTP clients to RestTemplate that I can use in my application?

Can I configure retry similar to spring retry and interceptors?

Comment: If you google it you can find [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/other/java-stuff/top-solutions-for-java-http-clients).

Comment: Thank you, in terms of retry, is there something similar to  
`@Retryable(
      value = { SQLException.class }, 
      maxAttempts = 2,
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
`Where Retry will be attempted only if the method throws an SQLException. There will be up to 2 retries and a delay of 5000 milliseconds.